# Teamcity automatic build configuration

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I wasnt able to find anything about creating or exporting my build configuration from TeamCity to import in another instance of TeamCity. Is it possible?

It will be valuable to have such thing like `xml` with build or all pipeline configuration.

There are two reasons for that:

1. Make it intependent and easyly moved to another TeamCity instance.
2. Have it scriptable for instance create `script/xml` that will create and setup jobs for me automatically.

If this is possible somehow please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamCity 9.0 introduced support for:

- [Moving projects between TeamCity servers](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/What%27s+New+in+TeamCity+9.0#What%27sNewinTeamCity9.0-MovingprojectsbetweenTeamCityservers), and
- [Storing project settings in Git and Mercurial](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/What%27s+New+in+TeamCity+9.0#What%27sNewinTeamCity9.0-StoringprojectsettingsinGitandMercurial)

If you want to script creation of build configurations, take a look at the [TeamCity REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API).

Comment: Thanks, helpful things!